# Find name that contain A and X with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and I would like to use the find() method with 2 differents strings.
I have in my database 'Mr. Robot' but if the user simply types 'Mr Robot' it doesn't return anything because of the dot.
So i have think about spliting 'Mr Robot' in an array composed of 'Mr' and 'Robot' and i would like to return the documents where the names contains 'Mr' and 'Robot'.
I tried something like that but it didn't worked:

```
Model.find({name: /Mr/, name: /Robot/});
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume `hi` and `bye` are the two words. So, the regex would be like this `/hi.*?bye.*/`.

**Correct me please, if I my regex is wrong.**

So, they query should look like this. Options `i` means case insensitive.

```
Model.find({ "name" : { $regex: /hi.*?bye.*/, $options: 'i' } });
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already split the `name` to an array you can use [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) to match all the items in that array, this is required beacuse if you check only by `name` for example `Robot`.

This might end up returning both `Mr. Robot` and `Mrs. Robot`. (Presumably multiple first name with different salutations might exist)

So you have to check for all the elements and make sure they are matching

```
Model.find( { name: { $all:  [ "Mr", "Robot" ]  } } ).
```

If you don't want to follow `name` splitting, Regex might the way to go